# Multiple people using same login at the same time

Tags: members

Is it acceptable to let multiple people use one member account at the same time? They will all be doing different things or even the same thing at the same time, eg: filling in a freeform form.

I know you can allow multiple logins for one account, but i just need to know if there is any complications by letting them all use the same account at the same time?

Scenario:
A specific department eg: Marketing team all use a member account called 'Marketing' instead of every person in that room having their own individual account?

Answer (score 1):

Well, one issue is that you are losing **accountability**. The audit track is nil in this situation. You don't know who edited what and when, and that makes it very hard to find out the why. You can make assumptions about a team; but never about a person. Someone having a bad day? Someone thinking (even if its not true) they're about to get fired? They might do something unwanted. Also, the team dynamics of one common-use password are a nightmare. I just wouldn't go there. It is the exact reason we use forwarding for email, and don't share one email account for multiple people in general.

This is what **Member Groups** are for. Create a Member Group for Marketing, and register users to that group. It's also more common; people are used to entering their own login ID (IE email address) and own password. It also puts that responsibility on the individual. We need to avoid a SPOF here (single point of failure).

Comment: Thanks for the reply @jrothafer, great points. I have individual logins for everyone apart from a small team of operatives. These operatives dont have work emails like everyone else so I just wanted to create one user that they could all log in with. The username and password would be on a whiteboard so no risk of forgetting and they would only have access to submitting one form, they would be in their own member group but I just wondered if this would cause complications technically eg: posting the form at the same time etc?